# For Loop in Batch Files

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

This is my code for creating and adding users to groups in a batch script file.

As you can see i have to hard code for ever varaible from T-Z. Is there any way to read the line grab the first delimters into a varaible and use it then reuse that varaible for the next delimter. I just want to cut this code down to the 2 dsadd group commands inside the for but get the same result.

%%D is just somthing along the lines of "Group1#Group2#Group3#Group4" that can hold a unknown number of groups.

```
FOR /F "tokens=1-7 delims=#" %%T IN ("%%D") DO (
  IF NOT [%%T] == [] (
    dsadd group cn="%%T",ou="GroupsOU",dc=advserver,dc=local
    dsmod group cn="%%T",ou="GroupsOU",dc=advserver,dc=local -addmbr cn="%%A %%B",ou="%%C",dc=advserver,dc=local
  )
  IF NOT [%%U] == [] (
    dsadd group cn="%%U",ou="GroupsOU",dc=advserver,dc=local
    dsmod group cn="%%U",ou="GroupsOU",dc=advserver,dc=local -addmbr cn="%%A %%B",ou="%%C",dc=advserver,dc=local
  )
  IF NOT [%%V] == [] (
    dsadd group cn="%%V",ou="GroupsOU",dc=advserver,dc=local
    dsmod group cn="%%V",ou="GroupsOU",dc=advserver,dc=local -addmbr cn="%%A %%B",ou="%%C",dc=advserver,dc=local
  )
  IF NOT [%%W] == [] (
    dsadd group cn="%%W",ou="GroupsOU",dc=advserver,dc=local
    dsmod group cn="%%W",ou="GroupsOU",dc=advserver,dc=local -addmbr cn="%%A %%B",ou="%%C",dc=advserver,dc=local
  )
  IF NOT [%%X] == [] (
    dsadd group cn="%%X",ou="GroupsOU",dc=advserver,dc=local
    dsmod group cn="%%X",ou="GroupsOU",dc=advserver,dc=local -addmbr cn="%%A %%B",ou="%%C",dc=advserver,dc=local
  )
  IF NOT [%%Y] == [] (
    dsadd group cn="%%Y",ou="GroupsOU",dc=advserver,dc=local
    dsmod group cn="%%Y",ou="GroupsOU",dc=advserver,dc=local -addmbr cn="%%A %%B",ou="%%C",dc=advserver,dc=local
  )
  IF NOT [%%Z] == [] (
    dsadd group cn="%%Z",ou="GroupsOU",dc=advserver,dc=local
    dsmod group cn="%%Z",ou="GroupsOU",dc=advserver,dc=local -addmbr cn="%%A %%B",ou="%%C",dc=advserver,dc=local
  )
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FOR /F "tokens=1-7 delims=#" %%T IN ("%%D") DO (
   FOR %%S IN (%%T %%U %%V %%W %%X %%Y %%Z) DO (

      dsadd group cn="%%S",ou="GroupsOU",dc=advserver,dc=local
      dsmod group cn="%%S",ou="GroupsOU",dc=advserver,dc=local -addmbr cn="%%A %%B",ou="%%C",dc=advserver,dc=local 

   )
)
```

If `%%D` contains a list of words separated by `#` this way: "Group1#Group2#Group3#Group4", then you may get an equivalent result with this code:

```
set groups=%%D
FOR %%T IN ("!groups:#=" "!") DO (

   dsadd group cn=%%T,ou="GroupsOU",dc=advserver,dc=local
   dsmod group cn=%%T,ou="GroupsOU",dc=advserver,dc=local -addmbr cn="%%A %%B",ou="%%C",dc=advserver,dc=local 

)
```

Previous code correctly works no matter the number of groups in `%%D`

Comment: First one works fine and perfect, but the second on doesn't work for me. It has do do with me being inside a For loop and not being able to set variables. I turned on SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION at top and the variable gets set fine but i still can't seem to use it in the (%groups:#= %) area. Do i need to change it to ! or something ?

Comment: Yes, just change percents by exclamation-marks: `(!groups:#= !)`

Comment: The %%T seems to be only holding the # now.

Comment: Ops! A small modification is needed in order to correctly work with delayed expansion, see the new version above. Note that `cn="%%T"` was changed to `cn=%%T` because `%%T` already include the quotes now.